# Order highest to lowest value without using MAX and ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to get the maximum count of a column for which I used `Count()` and wanted to order the column highest to lowest value without using `max` or `order by desc`.

I tried

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS CNT, student
FROM AUTHOR
GROUP BY student AU1
WHERE not exists (SELECT * FROM AUTHOR AU2 
                  WHERE AU2.student <> AU1.student AND AU2.subject > AU1.CNT)
```

but it doesn't return the desired output.

The desired output is the same as

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS CNT, student
FROM AUTHOR
GROUP BY Student
ORDER BY CNT DESC
```

but, without the `order by desc` or `MAX`.

Comment: Without explicit `ORDER BY` there is no order guaranteed at all

Comment: You can use RANK() but still, ORDER BY will be there :)

Comment: *"Without explicit ORDER BY there is no order guaranteed at all"* indeed what @LukaszSzozda says is very true. In fact without `ORDER BY` it is defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standards that the returning and sorting is platform depend most of the time it means the database will return the records in the order it matches from the table(s) but still the sorting of that resultset can be non deterministic (random) on every run, the only way to get truly deterministic (fixed) results always on every run in SQL is to always include a column which has a primary/unique key in the `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so DESC is not allowed and MAX is not allowed.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(subject) AS CNT, student
FROM
    AUTHOR
GROUP BY 
    Student
ORDER BY 
    -CNT
```

This does not work in each database software.
An other version:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
        COUNT(subject) AS CNT, student
    FROM
        AUTHOR
    GROUP BY 
        Student
    ) t
ORDER BY 
    -CNT
```

Comment: Actually  you don't need subquery, but I doubt that OP wants such solution

Comment: @quantummind when I use your query I am getting error like **Invalid column name 'COUNT** I am trying to fetch the highest count in the column.

Comment: @svisvesh OK, I've added an other version to work in mysql as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ORDER BY ASC`:

```
SELECT COUNT(subject) AS CNT, student
FROM AUTHOR
GROUP BY Student
ORDER BY (- CNT) ASC;
```

If you want the results in a particular order, you need to use `ORDER BY`.  That is one of the rules of using SQL.